# Load different images according to the receiving json response

Tags: android, json, image

Im getting a json response and from the im using of the item details to load in the menu grid, for that im using a adapter. at the moment i was able to load all the item details such as ImageURL , Description , Price. but i have the problem when loading the isVeg detail. isveg returns a true or false, then if the response is true then i have to load image1 and if the response is false then i have to laod the image2. where should check that n how to do it? where should i use the if condition if needed?

any help will be appreciated.

fragment class

```
           if ((object.getString("MainCategoryID")).equals("1")
                        && (object.getString("SubCategoryID")).equals("9")) {
                    Log.i("ImageURL ", object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    imageUrls.add(object.getString("ImageURL"));
                    Log.i("Description ", object.getString("Description"));
                    descriptions.add(object.getString("Description"));
                    Log.i("Price ", object.getString("Price"));
                    price.add(object.getString("Price"));
                    Log.i("IsVeg ", object.getString("IsVeg"));
                    isVeg.add(object.getString("IsVeg"));
                }
            }

            CustomGridPizza adapter = new CustomGridPizza(getActivity(), descriptions,
                    imageUrls, price);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

customgridpizzaadapter

```
    public class CustomGridPasta extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private final List<String> descriptions;
    private final List<String> imageUrls;
    private final List<String> price;
    private final List<String> isVeg;

    public CustomGridPasta(Context c, List<String> descriptions,
            List<String> imageUrls, List<String> price, List<String> isVeg) {
        this.context = c;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.imageUrls = imageUrls;
        this.price = price;
        this.isVeg = isVeg;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return descriptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return descriptions.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.pasta_single_item, parent, false);
            holder.ivImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            holder.tvImageIcon = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.icon);
            holder.tvHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvHeader.setText(descriptions.get(position));
        Picasso.with(this.context).load(imageUrls.get(position))
        .into(holder.ivImage);


        if (isVeg.equals(true)) {
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.veg);
    } else {
        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.nonveg);
    }
    holder.tvImageIcon.setImageBitmap(mBitmap); //mBitmap cannot be resolved to a variable

        Button customizePasta = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.bt_direct_customize);
        customizePasta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent next = new Intent(context, ActivityPastaCustomize.class);
                next.putExtra("description", descriptions.get(position));
                next.putExtra("imageUrl", imageUrls.get(position));
                next.putExtra("price", price.get(position));
                context.startActivity(next);
                ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(
                        R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvHeader;
        private ImageView ivImage;
        private ImageView tvImageIcon;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ` isVeg.add(object.optBoolean("IsVeg"));` instead of ` isVeg.add(object.getString("IsVeg"));`

Comment: my problem is how can i assign image1 when the response is true, assign image2 when the response is false. can i do that by using the above

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K i have edited my code as shown,im getting an error for getResourse(). what i have done is correct?

Comment: Use `this.context.getResources()` instead of `getResources()`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I could overcome this issue, but when i run it doesn't load the image can u find the issue with my code?. can u check my updated question?

Comment: call `holder.ivImage.setImageBitmap(image);` need to call `setImageBitmap(image);` to image in which want to set images

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I ddnt get your last comment. can u please tell me where should i do this change

Comment: where you want to use `veg` and `nonveg` images?

Comment: I want to use them in my grid menu. non veg food should get nonveg image like that. Im using this adapter to load the item name and image with that i want to use another image to show whther its veg or non veg

Comment: To show image in GridView item layout need to use a ImageView that's why im asking in which imageview want to show image like in `grid_image` or in `icon`

Comment: Now I need to show in icon. (i have done the grid_image)

Comment: then use `holder.tvImageIcon.setImageBitmap(image);`

Comment: it gives an error image cannot be resolved to a variable. Do u mind update ur code to my question and posting a answer

Comment: Sorry use `holder.tvImageIcon.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);`

Comment: I have changed the code as shown in my edited question and im still getting an error for mBitmap saying cannot be resolved to a variable. Can u check the code whether i hav added the code to correct place

Comment: Use as : `Bitmap mBitmap; if (isVeg.equals(true)) {mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.veg);} else {mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.nonveg);}`

Comment: that really worked thanks alot. but I have small problem if (isVeg.equals(true)), in this line isVeg is array[{true},{true},{false}]. because of that if (isVeg.equals(true)) always runs into else. what should i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position` to get value from `isVeg` List like:

```
String strIsVag=isVeg.get(position);
Bitmap mBitmap; 
if (strIsVag.contains("true")) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                              this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.veg);
    } else {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                           this.context.getResources(), R.drawable.nonveg);
}
```

Comment: my bad now it goes only inside the if condition. when i change the contains to equals then it goes only inside else condition how can i change this?

Comment: @JohnDavid: Check what value getting in `strIsVag` String and also share updated code

Comment: response im getting for `isVeg` ,

    [false, true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]

Comment: @JohnDavid: sorry my mistake use `if (strIsVag.contains("true"))` instead of `if (isVeg.contains("true"))`

Comment: Do u mind check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735577/assign-the-intended-bitmap-value-to-an-imageview